# Inserting text into textView by a button and then deleting

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

For example, I have a textview and a button above the textview.
I'm not a native English speaker and when I type "아아아아아" into the textView and then touch the input button three times, the text in the textView will become "아아아아아aaa" and if I delete one of the "a"s the text in the textView becomes "아아아아아a앙". I expect it to be "아아아아아aa". 아 consists of "ㅇ"+"ㅏ" which are a constant and a vowel.

Would anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

It appears that only when I type that happens. It doesn't seem like it happens after I paste 아아아아아 and insert "aaa" and delete one of the "a"s. And when I type only constants "ㅇㅇㅇㅇㅇ" and then add "aaa", it works well. And it also works well when I type in English and then add "aaa".
and if i touch the inside of the text view, after putting "aaa" into the textView, it also work well.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var input: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func input(_ sender: Any) {
        textViewTest.insertText("a")
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewTest: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textViewTest.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

What I have done so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var textViewTest: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var input: UIButton!

@IBAction func input(_ sender: Any) {
        textViewTest.replace(textViewTest.selectedTextRange!, withText: "a")
       
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textViewTest.backgroundColor = .green
    
}
```

}